# Declarative transaction management in EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, cdi

I know that the questions which refer to a link are not the favorite ones to the users of this great site, but I could not set my question in a different way. I am trying to delve into EJB and CDI and how they are properly used in real Web-Applications. I have read this [example](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/guide/GreeterQuickstart/) developed on JBoss application server. Close to the end it creates the class `ManagedBeanUserDao` and then the alternative `EJBUserDao` in order to save itself from handling the transaction management manually. I cannot fathom though, how he actually achieves that, since there are no refernce to transactions neither in the beans.xml file nor in the alternative class `EJBUserDao`.

My genaral question is how we avoid in a typical way the transaction management and if there is a link that explains it in detail. I have looked at the JavaEE Tutorial, but in the example it does not seem to follow exactly what the Tutorial states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EJBs are transactional by default. Invoking any of their method automatically starts a transaction, which is committed after the method returns (or rolled back in case of a runtime exception).

Comment: From your answer I infer that the first class "ManagedBeanUserDao" is not an EJB while the second "EJBUserDao" is. You may find my question of the layman 's level, but how is that defined? Only by using the annotation @Stateful, or by declaring it in beans.xml?

Comment: Yes. @Stateful declares a stateful session bean.

Comment: beans.xml is a configuration and marker file for CDI. There are some configuration option you can set (namely interceptors, alternatives and decorators), but mostly it's a marker file to tell CDI to pickup all the classes in the archive and use them as CDI beans. CDI beans are not, and probably will not be transactional by default. In Java EE 7 there's a new interceptor that's available to use, but you have to declare it via annotating the method of bean.